# In an ashx file, can I set the filename of the returned file?

Tags: asp.net, ashx

My ashx response.writes a simple text file that is returned. Can I change the filename, so if my ashx is located at mysite.com/someURL it doesn't return someURL.txt but rather, myFileName.txt ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [Content-Disposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) headed and [Response.AddHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.addheader?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) method for setting name of downloaded file.

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFileName.txt");
```